# What are USB Connectors made of?

Tags: usb, usb-device, manufacturing, materials, metal

What type of metal are the tips of USB connectors/plugs typically made from? Aluminium?

I've noticed they will often, quite-easily, oxidise/rust/corrode.

Comment: Which part is "the tips"? Do you mean the electrical contacts inside the plug/socket, the metal shield, or something else?

Comment: @gbulmer The tips; the extremities, the points of contact/termination. (So both, I guess?) Admittedly, I assumed they would all be the same material. But obviously there is a bit more to it than that.

Comment: Okay. I must admit, I have probably more than 100 USB cables, and I have never noticed rust or corrosion. The vast majority of my cables are full-size or full-size to mini USB. Is this a phenomena you've noticed on mini, micro or any USB?

Comment: @gbulmer Now that you mention it: Mini only, I think. Like the one often used by external USB WLAN interface cards and other small peripheral devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, quick search at Mouser gives:

For [this](http://br.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Hirose-Connector/ZX10-SLDB3301/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMulM8LPOQ%252bykxFWBnO0%252baHggWCaXh4sJKw%3D) model:

[image]

And for [this](http://br.mouser.com/ProductDetail/TE-Connectivity/2129691-1/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMulM8LPOQ%252byk9XlAzMldW6FcYHnhEzESm6MuGPpjn%2Fpug%3D%3D):

[image]

So I'd say stainless steel, some gold plated copper alloy(brass) and flame retardant plastic.

Comment: The contacts themselves are made of brass.  They are usually plated with gold.  Sometimes, they are plated with tin to save cost.

Comment: Very nice, cheers. I wonder why they plate it with a tin alloy; wouldn't it be better to just leave it stainless steel?

Comment: @NickAlexeev brass is a copper alloy :P (added your info to the answer)

Comment: @tjt263 SS would be very hard to solder on PCBs

Comment: Is that a fact? @WesleyLee

Comment: @tjt263  The shell needs to be soldered to the PCB for mechanical purposes.  It's difficult to solder to "raw" unplated stainless steel.  (If you have doubts, try to solder a copper wire to a piece of stainless using regular solder, regular flux, regular soldering iron temperature.)

Comment: @tjt263 well, soldering SS = brazing, which is unsuitable for electronics

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Is it to do with heat conductance?

Comment: I believe not. I dont know but I'd guess its something to do with chemical bonding of different metals. Just a wild guess.

Comment: Not bad for a wild guess, stainless steel grows a protective coating of nickel oxide, tin plating provides a surface that's easier to solder to (the tin will dissolve in the solder). once the stainless steel is wet with solder air is excluded, and no nickel oxide layer forms.